# Linear regression for coefficients regression

Tags: python, optimization, raster, coefficients

I'm trying to optimized 5 coefficients thanks to the comparaison of 2 raster images (.tiff). The equation looks like this : y = a1 + a2*x + a3*x^2 + a4*x^3 + a5*x^4 with x & y the pixel value of the 2 raster images and a the coefficients to optimize.

I'm facing 2 main issues :

- One of the raster is greater than the other (one is 608,232 and the other is 608,231)
- A lot of pixel have NA value in those raster images so I only want to do this optimization for matching pixels.

I search a lot in the gdal library to do so but don't find anything to do this.
Do anybody have an idea of how to do this ?
Thank's a lot

Comment: this appears to be a general math question as opposed to a coding issue...

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)